# Can you change the color of a checked CheckBox in Material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/checkbox

I have tried to set the style to have a color but it doesn't work, and I know there is a checkedIcon property that says it expects an 'element' but I'm not sure how to get the same shaped box from material and change the color.

Ideally I would be able to change both the check box background color and the color of the check mark.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `material-ui v1` and change colors by providing color attribute. I can't find it right now but I do remember reading somewhere on the official documentation that it is okay to mix the old and the new version.

Snippet would be like following

import React from 'react';
import Checkbox from 'material-ui/Checkbox';

```
class Checkboxes extends React.Component {
  state = {
    checkedA: true,
    checkedB: true,
    checkedF: true,
  };

  handleChange = name => event => {
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.checked });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        //this is red
        <Checkbox
          checked={this.state.checkedA}
          onChange={this.handleChange('checkedA')}
          value="checkedA"
        />
        //this is blue
        <Checkbox
          checked={this.state.checkedB}
          onChange={this.handleChange('checkedB')}
          value="checkedB"
          color="primary"
        />
        <Checkbox value="checkedC" />
        <Checkbox disabled value="checkedD" />
        <Checkbox disabled checked value="checkedE" />
        <Checkbox
          checked={this.state.checkedF}
          onChange={this.handleChange('checkedF')}
          value="checkedF"
          indeterminate
        />
        <Checkbox defaultChecked color="default" value="checkedG" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Checkboxes;
```

As to changing the colour of the tick itself, I do not think it is possible yet.